# Firewall-rules, cannot specify ports and protocols

Tags: google-compute-engine

When I try to create a new firewall rule I suddenly can't specify any ports or protocols it just jumps back to allow all. Does anyone know how to solve this and why I can't specify ports and protocols?

Comment: How are you creating the firewall rule - gcloud, Cloud Console or REST APIs ? If using gcloud or REST APIs, could you specify the command and/or the json request body ? Please redact any sensitive information like project name, secrets, etc.

Comment: I'm using Cloud Console to create the firewall rule. The first time I created a rule I had no problems and could specify ports, now I can click on the option but then it jumps back right away to "allow all".

Comment: What is the format you're using to specify ports? Is it showing any errors in red complaining about the format of the input?

Answer (score 0):

I went to the the google cloud console on my phone and tried to create the firewal rule again, somehow on my phone I could specify the ports. I then tried it on my computer with a different browser and it worked. I deleted my browser history and now it works fine in both browsers. Not quite sure what the error was.

**UPDATE:** When using Google Chrome, everything seems to be working fine.

Comment: Which browser did you use on your computer and on your phone?

Comment: The error occured in my safari web browser on my laptop. On my phone I use safari as well but there it worked. On my laptop I now use google chrome and everything works fine.